# How to test Codeigniter webservice with Postman extension in chrome

Tags: php, rest

I have build a login web service. But I don't understand how to test it with rest client.

The url is like this:
http://testapp.opinionbureau.com/webservice/sample/ob_login

You can see we are passing data  in below format with method name containing function to be called and data containing array of all variables required.

Array
(
    [method_name] => ob_login
    [data] => Array
        (
            [email] => test@aa.com
            [password] => test
            [cultureid] => 4
        )

)

in hidden input named 'req' in json format with base64 encode method. And in that function "ob_login" we first decode the data and process it accordingly.

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://testapp.opinionbureau.com/webservice/index">
<input id="req" name="req" value="eyJtZXRob2RfbmFtZSI6Im9iX2xvZ2luIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJlbWFpbCI6InByaW5jZV9ndXB0YTI2MTJAeWFob28uaW4iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6InNoYWt0aSIsImN1bHR1cmVpZCI6NH19" type="hidden">
<input value="Click To Post" type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I test this in Rest client.

Comment: Please check your question again. What the form look like?

Comment: The code of form is added. check now. It contains json data in base encode format.